# Secure Use of Dart SQLJocky

Tags: mysql, dart

I'm currently building a Dart application which needs to store SQL data in a centralised database. Normally I would do this via an ajax call to a PHP script (or REST service). I am keen however to keep this project as pure Dart language.

I've found a library called SQLJocky (details here: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky) but since Dart is a client side scripting language I am concerned about putting my database connection details on public display.

```
var pool = new ConnectionPool(host: 'localhost', port: 3306, user: 'bob', password: 'wibble', db: 'stuff', max: 5);
```

This seems to be targeted at people looking to build SQL Clients where the user enters the connection details.

My question is - can this library be used without disclosing the SQL connection details and if so, how? Even if it's a programming trick to hide the correct details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library won't run in the browser.
You can use Dart also on the server (without building to JavaScript).
SqlJocky is for such server applications.

Comment: Ah, I see - where do you find out which libraries will and won't run in the browser?

Comment: There were discussions about this but as far as I know there isn't a sure way to tell (yet). The package maintainer should make this clear in the package description but this isn't the case most of the time.